# removing last element from a multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a textbox that iterates 5 times and displays values from the textbox into an array.

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">   
 <?php for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) { 
     echo "<input type='text' name='text1[]'/>";    
  } ?>
<input type="submit" name="confirm" value="confirm" />
</form>


<?php
  $text1 = $_POST['text1'];
  $count= count($text1);
  if(isset($_POST['confirm'])) { 
    for($p = 0; $p < $count; $p++) {
       echo print_r($p[$i]);
    }
  }
?>
```

I want to remove the last value (which is that repeating number 1) from the data and only display the names. The output of above is as follows:-

```
John1
Jack1
Peter1
Jane1
Jill1
```

Comment: `substr($str, 0, -1)`?

Comment: Looking at your example I don't think that this works as you describe. It should be something like `echo $text1[$p];` instead of `echo print_r($p[$i]);`

Comment: thanks, it worked without print_r()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo print_r($p[$i]);
```

`print_r` prints content of `$p[$i]` and returns `1` that is passed to `echo` (and printed next to desired output). You don't need `print_r` here.

Answer (score 0):

`print_r` sends `$p[$i]` to the output buffer and then it returns a boolean result, which will be `true` (or `1` when echoed out).

So, the solution is simply to not use `print_r`.

Always [read the documentation](http://php.net/print_r) when you are unsure about something. Pretty much anything you want to know about PHP can be found there.